# How to open the datepicker by default in angular2?

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am using material design datepicker as shown below:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="eventDate"  placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The above code is working fine but, is it possible to open the datepicker popup always?

Can anyone suggest me how can i do this?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <mat-datepicker #picker opened="true"></mat-datepicker>
```

[mat-datepicker has an input opened, see angular material 2 documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api)

[image]

Comment: Forked an example for you here, make sure you're setting up opened property in mat-datepicker and not mat-datepicker-toggle  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysspzm?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html

Comment: Thanks for your response can the datepicker be opened all the time.. now if i click outside the popup its hiding..

Answer (score 0):

```
 <mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)" [minDate]="leaveMinDate"> </mat-calendar>
```